Combining Google Analytics Data with Internal Database for Custom Charts
We have Google Analytics set up on our web portal and store certain user-specific IDs (like department, company) in our database due to GDPR considerations.
We want to display custom charts within the user's web portal, showing things like:

User with the most requests
Most popular departments
Usage over time
This means we need to combine statistics from GA with the values from our database. We're considering using custom chart solutions to display this, but we're wondering if there's a simpler way.

Note:  We're open to replacing Google Analytics with a more suitable solution in the future if necessary.
Specific questions:

What are the recommended approaches for combining GA data with our internal database for this purpose?
Are there any built-in GA features or third-party tools that simplify this process?
If custom chart solutions are the best route, are there any specific libraries or frameworks you recommend?

